# Un problema de devolver vocales usando bucles en C

Tags: c, bucles

Hola quisiera consultarles el como poder plantear este problema para poder resolverlo el problema consta de dos partes:

pedir una cadena de caracteres de hasta 128 espacios y devolver por pantalla carácter por carácter

hasta ahí pude resolverlo
lo que me genera conflicto es el echo que debe devolver las vocales que contengan indicando cuales son anteriores a dicho carácter

Ej: hola
debería devolver esto
la vocal anterior al carácter H es :

la vocal anterior al carácter O es :

la vocal anterior al carácter L es :  o

la vocal anterior al carácter A es :  o

El mismo deberá ser resuelto con for o whiles exclusivamente

Adjuntare el código a continuación desde ya gracias

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 128

int main(){
    char palabra[MAX];
    int i=0;

    printf("Ingrese una cadena de caracteres las mismas deberan usar '_' en vez de espacios: \n");
      gets(palabra);
      system("cls");

while (palabra[i++]){
      printf("\nLas vocales anteriores al caracter %c son:",palabra[i-1]);
}
    printf("\n");
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Y que pasa si anterior a ese caracter hay mas vocales, se pondria solamente la vocal anterior, o todas las vocales que anteceden al caracter, por ejemplo Hola Mundo, al caracter "M", le anteceden las vocales a y o, habria que poner esas dos vocales o solamente la primera que anteceda al caracter "M"?

Comment: no en ese caso las dos van tipo en mundo seria algo asi 


la vocal anteriores al caracter m son :  o a
la vocal anteriores al caracter u son :  o a
la vocal anteriores al caracter n son :  o au
la vocal anteriores al caracter d son :  o au
la vocal anteriores al caracter o son :  o au

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la información que brindas no es del todo suficiente, podrías dar un ejemplo. Sin embargo, lo que entiendo es que si ingreso "overflow", luego sus vocales son "oeo" (se pueden repetir?) entonces el programa debe devolver "iai"?

Lo que podes hacer es crear un arreglo de char con las vocales:

`char vocales = {'a','e','i','o','u'};`

Luego, con un for doble (anidado) iteras sobre la palabra y vas comparando caracter por caracter con el arreglo 'vocales' hasta que encuentres una vocal. Dado el caso, con la variable del for vas a saber en que posición esta la vocal entonces haces vocales[i-1] y obtenes la vocal anterior (porque en el arreglo están ordenadas) y haces lo que quieras con ella.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Si lo que debería hacer es esto yo ingreso Ej.: hola 
debería devolver esto


la vocal anterior al carácter H es : 
la vocal anterior al carácter O es : 
la vocal anterior al carácter L es :  o
la vocal anterior al carácter A es : o

Comment: Buenisimo, ahi se entendio mejor. Entonces, se me ocurre que podes utilizar el codigo ascii: [enlace](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) de la siguiente manera: vas a tener 5 posibilidades; que tu caracter 'ch' este entre:

66 <= ch <= 68 ---> vocal anterior la A
70 <= ch <= 72 ---> vocal anterior la E
74 <= ch <= 78 ---> vocal anterior la I
80 <= ch <= 84 ---> vocal anterior la O
86 <= ch <= 90 ---> vocal anterior la U

te dejo para que veas de implementarlo con minusculas. Algo tedioso pero te va a funcionar.

Comment: osea gracias de ante mano pero a ver si entendi osea lo itero por valores osea uso los numeros ascii para definir las vocales y que el bucle las recorra y cuando coincidan itere para atras ?

Comment: Se mezclaron las ideas porque al principio no estaba claro cual era el objetivo. Ahora si, entonces como vos decis tenes que usar los ascii para comparar caracter por caracter de la palabra leida. Podes hacer un metodo que te resuelva el problema.


`void buscarVocal(unsigned char ch){
    char vocales[]={'A','E','I','O','U'};
    for (int i= 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (vocales[i] == ch){
            cout<<"la vocal es" <<ch<< endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    int vAscii=(int)ch;
    if(66<=vAscii and vAscii<=68)   cout << "la vocal anterior a"<<ch<<" es A"<< endl;
}`

Comment: si ahora entiendo tu planteamiento pero el ejercicio pide explícitamente que sea for y condicionales anidados por eso es que me causa tanta abrumacion la verdad por eso mismo les agradezco una locura su ayuda

Comment: bueno, para tu proxima pregunta entonces te recomiendo que aclares bien todas las condiciones que tengas...

Comment: tenes razon mala mia ahi lo edite nuevamente gracias..